# Ошибка удаления объекта core data

Tags: objective-c, coredata

У меня есть 2 экрана первый показывает список тренировок (таблица), нажимаем на ячейку, грузим список (таблица) упражнений. 
все связано и хранится в БД (core data) 
Если я захожу на экран тренировок и удаляю ячейку (тренировку) методом

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.deletePath]];
[self saveContext];
```

все ок, все удаляется, но стоит зайти на экран упражнений, и потом нажать назад `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Попадаю на свой список тренировок, и пытаюсь удалить тем же методом, то возникает ошибка

> -[_UIPreviewInteractionForceLevelClassifier controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x175e08e0 2016-05-05 14:10:07.012 [3863:2402185] CoreData: error:
>   Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data
>   change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of
>   NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   -[_UIPreviewInteractionForceLevelClassifier controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x175e08e0 with userInfo (null) 2016-05-05 14:10:07.012[3863:2402185]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[_UIPreviewInteractionForceLevelClassifier
>   controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x175e08e0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x21621b8b 0x20ddedff 0x216274d5 0x2162512b 0x2154f358 0x232324ad 0x2313ed83 0x215d3345 0x215d2d53
>   0x215d2b29 0x21629f63 0x215320eb 0x21d77b17 0x2313eceb 0x231aae19
>   0x2313d36b 0x23135dfb 0x215e3331 0x215e1627 0x215e1a65 0x21530289
>   0x2153007d 0x22b4caf9 0x25c5b2c5 0x2ac3f9 0x211dc873) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: Вам стоит добавить метку `iOS`. Приложение в эмуляторе ведь? Попробуйте поставить точку останова, дело может прояснится, кто, кому и почему отправил сообщение. Ставится _symbolic breakpoint_ на `-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` в навигаторе точек останова.

Answer (score 1):

`NSFetchedResultsController` вызывает у своего делегата метод `-controllerWillChangeContent:` при появлении изменений в отслеживаемых объектах. Свойство `delegate` у FRC объявлено как `@property (nonatomic, assign)` – похоже, это означает, что это свойство при освобождении вашего делегата всё ещё будет указывать на то место в памяти, где он когда-то был. Пока свойство `delegate` у FRC не-nil, он будет отслеживать изменения в контексте и при обнаружении изменений будет уведомлять делегата. Если по указанному в свойстве `delegate` адресу теперь сидит другой объект, не реализующий методы протокола `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, то будет выброшено исключение вроде вашего.

Попробуйте в своих контроллерах сделать:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.frc.delegate = self;
    [self.frc performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.frc.delegate = nil;
}
```

И в целом – поищите, где могут не освобождаться FRC.