# Update TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, coredata

Добрый день, при добавление функций controllerWillChangeContent, controller,controllerDidChangeContent обновление таблицы, вылетает ошибка в консоль после того, когда захожу во второй раз в ViewController и таблица перестает реагировать:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadDataFireBaseKind()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "KindOfAnimal")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "kind", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self


        do {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            kindOfAnimals = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [KindOfAnimal]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    kindTableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            kindTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
    case .Delete:
        if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            kindTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
    case .Update:
        if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            kindTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
    default:
        kindTableView.reloadData()
    }
    kindOfAnimals = controller.fetchedObjects as! [KindOfAnimal]
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    kindTableView.endUpdates()
}

func loadDataFireBaseKind(){

    firebaseKind.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        self.deleteAllData("KindOfAnimal")

        for list in snapshot.children {
            let kindList = Kinds(snapshot: list as! FDataSnapshot)

            if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
                self.kindAnimal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("KindOfAnimal", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! KindOfAnimal

                self.kindAnimal.kind = kindList.kind;

                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

    }) {(error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

> NotebookAnimal[8499:183864] CoreData: error: Serious application
>   error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Comment: А попробуйте во `viewDidLoad` сделать свифтовый аналог `NSLog(@"1: %p", fetchResultController);`, а в `controllerWillChangeContent:` `NSLog(@"2: %p", controller);`. У меня есть серьёзные подозрения, что у вас не освобождается FRC, созданный на первом заходе в контроллер.

Comment: Вот результат в первый раз:
NotebookAnimal[12766:328139]  1: 0x7fd81bc63800
129 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
150 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
153 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
157 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
160 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
162 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
165 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800
168 NotebookAnimal[12704:325080] 2: 0x7fd81bc63800

Comment: Тут всё хорошо, объект FRC, вызывающий делегатные методы, тот же самый, что был создан во `viewDidLoad`. А второй раз?

Comment: И повторный вход на ViewController:

NotebookAnimal 1: 0x7fc90bc15490
326 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
326 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1716
327 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
328 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1716

Comment: 330 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
331 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
332 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
332 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
333 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
334 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
335 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
335 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
337 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
337 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
339 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470

Comment: 339 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490
340 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470
341 NotebookAnimal[12766:328139] 2: 0x7fc90bc15490

Comment: Ну вот они, два разных FRC: 1: 0x7fc90bc15490 / 2: 0x7fc90bc7c470 / 2: 0x7fc90bc15490. То-есть при втором заходе создаётся тот, что сидит по адресу 0x7fc90bc15490, но и прошлый, который по адресу 0x7fc90bc7c470, тоже никуда не делся, и продолжает отслеживать изменения в контексте, уведомляя о них делегата. Недавно отвечал на похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520534/183326 . В вашем случае стоит попробовать ставить `fetchResultController.delegate = nil` в некоем свифтовом аналоге метода `-dealloc`.

Comment: И кстати, похоже, что ваш контроллер тоже не освобождается. Или это так и задумано?

Comment: А вот ещё: `kindTableView.reloadData()` в `didChangeObject` – это в корне не правильно. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates . Там так и сказано: `You should not call reloadData within the group;`. И ещё я не вижу делегатного метода `
- controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:`. См. тут: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/ , в Typical Use.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать?

Comment: 1. Добавить `-controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` – пусть будет. 2. Заменить `default: kindTableView.reloadData()` на `case .Move: удалить/вставить строку`. 3. Добавить `deinit { fetchResultController.delegate = nil }`. Поискать, что держит `UIViewController`, если после всего этого вызовы делегатных методов всё ещё будут двоиться.

Comment: Кстати, покажите (можно вопрос отредактировать и добавить в него) методы протокола `UITableViewDataSource` – это которые `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` и `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, как минимум. В них надо возвращать _текущее_ состояние объектов FRC. Эти методы работают согласованно с методами протокола `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` – которые `-controllerWillChangeContent:` и т.д.

Comment: Добавил:
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            kindTableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            kindTableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
        }
    }

Comment: Заманил default: kindTableView.reloadData() и добавил deinit
К сожалению изменения ни каких нету

Comment: func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return kindOfAnimals.count
    }

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40496/discussion-between-bteapot-and-d-dante).